# replace js with php echo without refresh

Tags: javascript, php

The situation is I've write-out code like

```
<input type="text" name="date"<?php if(empty($date)){echo 'id="date"';}else{echo 'value='.$date;} ?> readonly/>
```

whole page coded

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['rec_id']))
    {
        $enginenumber = $_SESSION['engn'];
        $model = $_SESSION['mod'];
        $vinnumber = $_SESSION['vinn'];
        $date = $_SESSION['date'];
        $time = substr($_SESSION['time'],0,5);
        $bikeid = $_SESSION['bk_id'];
        $recid = $_SESSION['rec_id'];
    }
    else
    {
        $enginenumber = "";
        $model = "";
        $vinnumber = "";
        $date = "";
        $time = "";
    }
    $_SESSION['line'] = $_GET['line'];
    $linenumber = $_SESSION['line'];
    $_SESSION['station'] = $_GET['st'];
    include('../../php/dbconnectmssql.php');
?>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>TH Bike Assembly RFT Database</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/reset.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/external.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/formrecords.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/inputtabconroll2c.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/date_time.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jsdialog.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/validate.js">window.onload=function(){validateform();}</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.onload=function(){GetClock();setInterval(GetClock,1000);}</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main rft">
            <h1>Right First Time Record Line <?php echo $linenumber; ?> Chassis</h1>
            <form name="stationrec" method="post" action="../php/stationrec.php">
                <table class="headform">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>VinNumber</p>
                            <input type="text" name="vinnumber" value="<?php echo $vinnumber; ?>"
                            <?php if(!empty($vinnumber)){echo "readonly";} ?>/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>Engine Number</p>
                            <input type="text" name="enginenumber" value="<?php echo $enginenumber; ?>"
                            <?php if(!empty($enginenumber)){echo "readonly";} ?>/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>Model</p>
                            <input type="text" name="model" value="<?php echo $model; ?>"
                            <?php if(!empty($model)){echo "readonly";} ?>/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Date</p>
                            <input type="text" name="date"
                            <?php if(empty($date)){echo 'id="date"';}else{echo 'value="'.$date.'"';} ?> readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>Time</p>
                            <input type="text" name="time"
                            <?php if(empty($date)){echo 'id="time"';}else{echo 'value="'.$time.'"';} ?> readonly/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="" class="myButton" type="submit" value="Bike-Pass/NewBike"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <div id="faultpanel" class="container">
                    <div class="">
                        <h2>Fault Records</h2>
                        <div class="tabbedcontain">
                            <ul class="col4">
                                <li id="fhlschs" onclick="scchs()">Chassis</li>
                                <li id="fhlsuk" onclick="scuk()">UK</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ftlscon">
                            <div id="ftlschs" class="col8">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Main Problem</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>FoundBy</th>
                                        <th>Chassis Number</th>
                                        <th>Station</th>
                                        <th>Damage Grade</th>
                                        <th>More Info</th>
                                        <th>Inv Chs Need</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    if(isset($_SESSION['rec_id']))
                                    {
                                        $sql = "select mainproblem,location,chassisNo,foundby,station,damage_grade,moreinfo,invchss
                                                from dbo.fault_st2_rec
                                                where st2_rec_id like ".$recid."and c_id like 5";
                                        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn , $sql);
                                        if($query === false)
                                        {
                                            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
                                        }
                                        while ($count = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                                        {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            foreach($count as $x => $a)
                                            {
                                                echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
                                            }
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div id="ftlsuk" class="col5">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Main Problem</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>Cause By</th>
                                        <th>Found By</th>
                                        <th>More Info</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                    if(isset($_SESSION['rec_id']))
                                    {
                                        $sql = "select mainproblem,location,causeby,foundby,moreinfo
                                                from dbo.fault_st2_rec
                                                where st2_rec_id like ".$recid."and c_id like 6";
                                        $query = sqlsrv_query($conn , $sql);
                                        if($query === false)
                                        {
                                            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
                                        }
                                        while ($count = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                                        {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            foreach($count as $x => $a)
                                            {
                                                echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
                                            }
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="add" class="myButton" type="button" value="Add Problem" onclick="formshow()">
                    <input id="" class="myButton" type="button" value="Back" onclick="recmanu()"/>
                    <div id="addform" class="popupformcontainer">
                        <div class="popupform">
                            <div class="tabbedcontain">
                                <ul class="col2">
                                    <li id="chs" onclick="scchs()">Chassis</li>
                                    <li id="uk" onclick="scuk()">UK</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="formcontain">
                                <div id="chsprob">
                                    <form name="chassis" action="php/svfultrec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm('chassis',['mainprob','location','foundby','chsno','station','damg'])" method="post">
                                        <h2>Fault by Chassis</h2>
                                        <table class="fromtable">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Main Problem</td>
                                                <td><input name="mainprob" type="text" placeholder="Mainproblem"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Location</td>
                                                <td><input name="location" type="text" placeholder="Location"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Found By</td>
                                                <td><input name="foundby" type="text" placeholder="Found By"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Chassis No</td>
                                                <td><input name="chsno" type="text" placeholder="Chassis No"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Station</td>
                                                <td><input name="station" type="text" placeholder="Station"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Damage Grade</td>
                                                <td><input name="damg" type="text" placeholder="Damage Grade"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>More Info</td>
                                                <td><input name="mrinfo" type="text" placeholder="More Info"</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Inv Chs Need ?</td>
                                                <td><input id="checkbox" name="invst" type="checkbox" value="true"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                    <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Add" name="chassis"/>
                                                    <input class="myButton" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                                                    <input class="myButton" type="button" value="Cancle" onclick="formhide()"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div id="ukprob">
                                    <form name="uk" action="php/svfultrec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm('uk',['mainprob','location','foundby'])" method="post">
                                        <h2>Fault by UK</h2>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Main Problem</td>
                                                <td><input name="mainprob" type="text" placeholder="Mainproblem"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Location</td>
                                                <td><input name="location" type="text" placeholder="Location"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Cause By</td>
                                                <td><input name="causeby" text="text" placeholder="Cause By"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Found By</td>
                                                <td><input name="foundby" type="text" placeholder="Found By"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>More Info</td>
                                                <td><input name="mrinfo" type="text" placeholder="More Info"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Add" name="uk"/>
                                                    <input class="myButton" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
                                                    <input class="myButton" type="button" value="Cancle" onclick="formhide()"/>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's about input form.
any information that i can give please ask me

Problem is ... when the variable is not empty,
(that's mean php echo out `'value ='.$date`)
values is not replaced by php that i echo.

I need to refresh the page to get value display properly.

And I've also checkout in developer tool of google chrome to view source code, thing is ..... it was replaced but it need to be refresh every time to make it display properly.

what i want to do is, how can i get value that echo display properly without refresh page,or other kind of things ?

//Pure js/php would be nice

**updated**
in IE rendering output working properly

**updated2**
I've write out code that made it refresh page again for temporary, i still want to know is it possible to make it display properly without refresh page ?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['refresh']))
    {
        if($_SESSION['refresh'] === true)
        {
            echo "<script> window.location.reload(); </script>";
            $_SESSION['refresh'] = false;
        }
    }
```

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks

Comment: Where does `$date` come from? It sounds like you are misunderstanding client variables and server variables.

Comment: `'value="' . $date . '"';`. Add the quotes.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev it's coded before this line

Comment: @b0s3 thanks i've try but it's not working :(

Comment: i think it's all about cache that store before

Answer (score 0):

Add double or single quotes here `'value='.$date;}`

Change from

```
<input type="text" name="date"<?php if(empty($date)){echo 'id="date"';}else{echo 'value='.$date;} ?> readonly/>
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="date"<?php if(empty($date)) echo 'id="date"'; else echo "value=\"$date\""; ?> readonly/>
```

Comment: wait a second what's difference with those 2

Comment: i've try replace that code but it's same :(
like i said i've check source code and is echo out **<input type="text" name="date" value="08/13/2015" readonly>** properly but it not display properly i need to refresh the page every time :(

Comment: @TrinPongtaman what is issue in `display`? Did not get it, why you want to refresh page?

Comment: my flow is if there's no $date or it's empty it's will echo out **id="date"** that's link with javascript function, that i use to show current time, but if I've submit form and I've get $date form database that i coded it will echo out $date, yes it work but only page source coded (ctrl+u in chrome) , but it's not display in browser, so i need to refresh every time to make it display properly. i guess it's about cache or something that made browser still display time from js function

Comment: @TrinPongtaman I need more code from you. Please add your full page code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

PHP works as it should be but your `html` does not render the output properly as your generated `html` code contains some error. From your code if `$date` is not empty(for example it contains 17-08-2015) it will give output something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="date"value=17-08-2015 readonly/>
```

But it should be something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="17-08-2015" readonly/>
```

So change your php code to generate proper output. Like:

```
<input type="text" name="date" <?php if(empty($date)){echo 'id="date"';}else{echo 'value="'.$date.'";} ?> readonly/>
```

Comment: they get the same output.... yes the html change but it still rendering out date that I've get from javascript function i've no idea why
**<input type="text" name="date" value="08/13/2015" readonly>**

Comment: what you are getting and what it should be? Give generated `html` code from source code of your browser. @TrinPongtaman

Comment: the coded that I've comment before **<input type="text" name="date" value="08/13/2015" readonly>** is generated by browser, but  browser still render out time that i input form (from js function). what i want is it should replaced by "08/13/2015", there's only way ... refresh page

Comment: $date variable contain null if there's no data sent from anything // look at my whole page coded i've updated

Comment: So every thing is working as it is? `$date` is getting value from `SESSION` and it displays in value. you can `echo` values of `$date` outside form to check.

Comment: **<?php echo '<h3>'.$date.$time.'</h3>'; ?>** it's echo out properly !!

Comment: So is this `$date` is not same as in date input field (**08/13/2015**)?

Comment: updated i've try to check to input with IE and it's work properly problem cause only with chrome

Comment: i didn't get it sorry